# How to get to the different nodes of svg document( ie, title, path in each group)

Tags: javascript, svg

I am trying to get an array of groups, and get the title node and path node. I keep getting confused on what I should use to do this. This is a shortened version of the svg document that I am using.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<svg
   xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
   viewBox="-29.947200 60.986600 2754.066400 1200.573900"
   version="1.1"
   id="WorldMap">
  <g class="land pe" id="pe">
    <title>Peru</title>
    <path
       d="M 648.6568,798.4085 C 649.7424,796.3496 650.3516,794.9406 651.9945,793.1866 C 652.7283,792.4035 653.3084,791.4646 654.1824,790.8206 C 654.8156,790.3536 656.1752,789.7275 656.2689,788.8275 C 657.2520,789.1115 658.1313,793.1756 657.2450,793.6835 C 656.5998,794.0535 655.8948,793.7206 655.4142,794.3655 C 654.8657,795.1005 654.9399,796.1025 655.9582,796.2476 C 655.0648,797.3736 655.3714,799.0856 656.7668,797.6486 C 657.9912,796.3876 658.4138,796.9855 659.4871,797.9275 C 660.4068,798.7355 661.5495,797.5105 662.2500,798.7265 C 662.9692,799.9765 662.9082,802.0466 664.6843,802.3836 C 666.1842,802.6685 666.3388,802.8536 666.9148,801.2065 C 667.3747,799.8926 668.8395,799.5646 668.9609,798.2225 C 669.1248,796.4066 669.4767,794.7626 670.2927,793.0775 C 670.7117,792.2115 671.2559,791.5865 671.3107,790.5906 C 671.3456,789.9585 672.1519,788.2096 672.4408,789.9076 C 672.6979,789.5176 672.7618,789.1075 672.6322,788.6785 C 672.5967,788.1255 673.4299,787.5276 673.7411,787.1366 C 674.5513,786.1155 675.5439,785.3586 676.7253,784.8275 C 679.2958,783.6716 682.2668,783.2465 684.6343,781.6486 C 689.6128,778.2866 693.1525,773.2536 694.1922,767.5176 C 694.5872,767.9345 695.0666,768.1005 695.6324,768.0176 C 694.9156,766.3575 695.6582,764.8886 694.6639,763.4715 C 694.2726,762.9135 692.3296,761.2165 692.4480,760.5276 C 693.2653,760.6666 694.2190,760.9456 694.9920,760.4865 C 695.7580,760.0326 695.5146,759.8845 696.3804,760.2056 C 697.8738,760.7586 698.9792,761.3505 700.0121,762.5915 C 701.3548,764.2065 702.1132,764.8025 702.7589,766.8676 C 703.0289,767.7286 702.6975,768.4325 703.8848,768.5355 C 705.0360,768.6355 704.7361,769.0956 705.5337,769.8066 C 707.0808,771.1875 708.2162,770.4525 708.7595,772.8095 C 709.1376,774.6355 709.0426,775.0746 710.9673,775.6576 C 713.0414,776.2855 710.9656,778.7336 711.9900,779.9535 C 712.5458,780.6146 713.4435,780.8396 714.2932,780.8045 C 714.8252,780.7336 715.3592,780.6866 715.8943,780.6626 C 716.6026,780.6645 717.4140,781.0806 718.0432,781.0585 C 719.4889,781.0045 721.2381,779.9646 721.9121,778.7056 C 722.6237,777.3765 724.3541,779.9176 725.1421,779.9786 C 726.3301,780.0706 728.2345,778.3475 729.0595,778.9686 C 729.7181,779.4646 730.2872,780.2165 730.9228,780.6635 C 731.5330,781.0936 733.0100,780.9765 733.3800,781.3855 C 734.8927,783.0556 734.8944,783.6576 733.5911,785.6055 C 732.5473,787.1656 730.5320,789.8346 730.1908,791.6495 C 729.7822,793.8206 732.3497,792.1205 733.2592,792.9406 C 733.9935,793.6015 734.5523,794.4886 735.0578,795.3306 C 735.6388,796.2956 735.1639,797.8425 734.3336,796.3886 C 734.1314,796.6286 733.9292,796.8686 733.7260,797.1086 C 732.6592,795.5846 730.2059,794.5925 728.7222,796.3795 C 727.0303,798.4176 723.5334,797.8795 721.1886,798.4936 C 719.9605,798.8156 719.3212,800.1635 718.1019,800.5385 C 716.8207,800.9335 717.2130,801.4406 716.3405,802.1985 C 714.2491,804.0176 712.8686,803.4955 712.7185,806.6136 C 712.6658,807.6946 712.6970,808.6005 712.0264,809.5416 C 711.3875,810.4366 710.6312,811.3335 710.8275,812.4805 C 711.0311,813.6706 711.9944,815.3626 710.6256,816.2805 C 709.4738,817.0516 708.3977,817.4456 707.4366,818.5205 C 706.7353,819.3045 706.3517,820.1956 706.5261,821.2286 C 706.6220,821.7286 706.7778,822.2096 706.9893,822.6685 C 706.4175,822.9116 705.8207,823.2165 705.3775,823.6695 C 703.6677,825.4176 708.4053,826.9345 706.3765,828.1376 C 707.3528,828.7926 707.9942,829.9886 708.1536,831.1526 C 708.2468,831.8335 708.7066,832.0706 709.1822,832.4675 C 709.7778,832.9636 709.6850,833.7196 710.0652,834.3375 C 710.7335,835.4206 712.0936,835.9306 712.5405,837.1845 C 713.0738,838.6795 711.8784,839.5925 711.0049,840.6676 C 712.7472,841.5975 715.4084,840.7616 717.1280,841.9345 C 718.2446,842.6956 719.2182,844.6735 718.7153,846.0675 C 721.1000,846.3676 724.1416,846.8845 726.3491,845.4316 C 727.7360,844.5145 729.6379,841.1996 731.4507,841.1775 C 731.2004,842.0445 730.5215,842.0886 731.0143,842.9846 C 731.5367,843.9356 730.5505,844.8845 730.5627,845.9706 C 730.5164,848.7945 730.3850,851.6906 730.5071,854.4976 C 731.5035,853.6845 732.0031,855.3465 732.9821,855.2526 C 734.3321,855.1226 735.3554,854.0525 736.7296,854.0856 C 737.9924,854.1155 738.7376,854.0506 739.2868,855.2376 C 740.1215,857.0385 740.9835,858.8166 741.8451,860.6055 C 742.7133,862.4066 743.5578,864.2215 744.4773,865.9955 C 745.1519,867.2945 745.7043,868.6255 744.1880,869.8396 C 742.8701,870.8945 743.0925,872.2736 743.1166,873.7405 C 743.1421,875.3346 742.4278,877.7125 742.8745,879.1566 C 743.1456,880.0316 743.9232,880.8565 743.8892,881.8285 C 743.8866,881.8886 742.8649,884.1946 742.7925,884.2555 C 741.8466,885.0476 741.0765,886.3406 740.5795,887.4456 C 739.6706,889.4646 741.8021,889.7785 741.6853,891.3475 C 741.6017,892.4615 740.5011,893.3845 740.2068,894.4646 C 739.9236,895.4145 740.4587,896.5975 740.7109,897.4575 C 740.9458,898.2576 741.3073,899.7835 742.3012,899.9656 C 742.7808,900.0535 745.3417,900.2505 743.6572,901.2465 C 742.5273,901.9145 743.2999,903.5276 742.5924,903.8926 C 741.2536,904.5846 740.8089,906.4485 739.7335,907.3955 C 739.2650,907.8085 738.6654,908.0326 738.2661,908.5295 C 737.5099,909.4706 738.5389,909.1735 738.9383,909.7945 C 739.9792,911.4166 737.4347,911.7826 736.8339,912.7876 C 736.1577,913.9166 737.2394,915.2595 736.3213,916.5556 C 735.5304,917.6716 734.0881,918.0666 732.8543,918.0666 C 731.4693,918.0666 730.5228,917.0476 729.6863,916.1756 C 728.6999,915.1486 727.5449,914.6676 726.4464,913.8315 C 724.4979,912.3486 724.9775,909.6505 722.5556,908.6205 C 719.6903,907.4005 718.0102,904.4986 714.9184,903.7246 C 713.4715,903.3626 712.0639,902.3456 710.8658,901.5495 C 709.4321,900.5975 707.7951,900.2785 706.3194,899.4375 C 704.8757,898.6126 703.7196,897.3525 702.2787,896.4805 C 700.6585,895.5005 699.0337,894.5395 697.3552,893.5865 C 695.9376,892.7816 695.1975,890.9356 694.1291,889.7465 C 692.7138,888.1706 690.6028,887.3425 689.6862,885.3866 C 689.1697,884.2826 688.5055,882.9565 687.4919,882.2916 C 686.6056,881.7096 688.0364,879.4855 686.3740,879.7655 C 686.4171,879.4846 686.5114,879.2175 686.6599,878.9656 C 686.8918,879.1096 687.1215,879.2565 687.3490,879.4055 C 688.2656,876.2075 687.0116,874.5495 685.6182,871.9295 C 684.3528,869.5495 683.5698,867.0326 681.6786,865.0975 C 681.1118,864.5166 680.5085,864.2106 680.7444,863.4156 C 681.0157,862.5005 680.5637,861.4736 680.1889,860.7115 C 679.8211,859.9625 679.3674,859.1595 678.7466,858.5946 C 678.1754,858.0735 677.1451,857.8265 676.8187,857.0685 C 676.8045,856.6716 676.8746,856.2776 677.0277,855.8886 C 676.9801,855.0255 676.5148,854.0376 676.1852,853.2736 C 675.5541,851.8085 674.6325,850.5105 673.9153,849.0946 C 673.2396,847.7605 672.9167,846.1626 672.4266,844.7255 C 671.2835,841.3696 669.3041,838.7855 668.5163,835.5406 C 667.4405,831.1115 663.7984,828.4156 662.3009,824.0406 C 660.5645,819.0366 656.6648,815.4706 651.8435,813.4066 C 651.4191,813.2246 649.8166,812.8365 649.7868,812.2396 C 649.7458,811.4076 649.6292,810.0195 650.8206,810.1676 C 652.9402,810.4316 652.2162,808.4216 651.5710,807.3745 C 650.6605,805.8976 649.7187,805.2805 649.7454,803.4435 C 649.9528,803.2075 650.1553,802.9675 650.3529,802.7236 C 650.3287,802.4435 649.5110,801.6695 649.3308,801.4556 C 648.3827,800.3356 649.0196,799.6756 648.6568,798.4085"
       id="pe1" />

  </g>
  <g class="land gf" id="gf">
    <title>French Guiana</title>
    <path
     d="M 853.0452,739.4375 C 854.3325,739.3776 855.3084,737.1695 855.7246,736.2006 C 856.5002,734.3916 855.6456,732.3786 856.8415,730.7305 C 858.2597,728.7776 856.8800,727.3375 855.5955,725.7826 C 854.2633,724.1695 854.2465,721.2895 854.0752,719.3216 C 853.8760,717.0285 854.1794,715.7255 855.8172,714.1286 C 856.4271,713.5335 857.1889,712.8765 857.3684,711.9976 C 857.6008,710.8586 857.8616,709.4356 859.4943,710.0456 C 860.5538,710.4416 861.2942,711.2895 862.4175,711.5946 C 863.6306,711.9256 865.0940,711.9066 866.1329,712.7206 C 867.3514,713.6775 869.0259,717.3225 870.9009,717.1896 C 870.5961,717.6516 870.3914,718.1555 870.2859,718.7025 C 870.7633,716.3066 874.9695,720.4176 872.6658,722.0145 C 873.7899,721.5975 873.1066,720.5395 873.6541,719.7855 C 874.4851,718.6395 875.2123,721.3106 875.2915,721.8795 C 875.6657,724.5775 873.6586,727.4335 872.3034,729.5815 C 870.7467,732.0495 869.6730,734.1386 868.6857,736.9195 C 868.3194,737.9515 867.8364,738.8246 866.9852,739.5266 C 866.6318,739.8185 866.0021,740.4905 865.5308,740.6155 C 864.7542,740.8225 864.1243,740.1975 863.2981,740.5915 C 863.6193,739.6105 863.0038,739.6065 862.2718,739.8346 C 861.2487,740.1535 860.3584,739.7346 859.3710,739.4035 C 858.8727,739.2365 856.9837,740.6286 856.6852,740.9936 C 856.1311,741.6706 853.4319,739.8346 853.0452,739.4375"
     id="gf1" />

  </g>
  <g class="land bf" id="bf">
    <title>Burkina Faso</title>
    <path
       d="M 1228.2624,669.2376 C 1228.7782,667.8546 1229.1945,666.3886 1228.8503,664.9095 C 1228.4738,663.2926 1229.3082,664.1906 1229.9106,662.9786 C 1230.2827,662.2286 1231.3192,660.0036 1230.3779,659.3745 C 1229.6073,658.8596 1230.6017,657.5716 1229.1678,657.2146 C 1230.0071,657.2565 1230.4091,656.6055 1231.0407,656.2175 C 1232.0725,655.5856 1233.4797,656.1046 1234.5447,655.4525 C 1235.8474,654.6555 1237.7150,651.6065 1236.4155,650.2006 C 1235.8925,649.6355 1236.8673,649.0835 1237.3779,649.2025 C 1238.4587,649.4535 1238.3766,648.3425 1238.2013,647.4825 C 1238.0856,646.9206 1236.9528,646.0856 1237.9230,645.7486 C 1238.6695,645.4886 1239.6730,643.3855 1240.1331,642.7415 C 1240.0900,644.0076 1243.1214,645.5195 1244.1653,645.6226 C 1243.9033,644.4216 1244.6920,644.5806 1245.6746,644.6146 C 1245.5282,643.5166 1246.0615,642.0236 1245.4764,641.0136 C 1246.2965,641.1685 1247.1457,641.2255 1247.8856,641.6616 C 1248.9666,640.0236 1248.7870,636.4275 1251.6452,636.1345 C 1253.0537,635.9905 1254.9408,638.1605 1255.1892,635.6845 C 1255.3219,634.3565 1256.6916,634.5725 1257.6039,634.1005 C 1258.7865,633.4896 1259.6188,632.4285 1260.9221,632.0145 C 1262.8073,631.4145 1265.0735,627.6845 1267.1804,629.5416 C 1267.5803,629.8936 1268.5339,629.0746 1269.1731,629.2655 C 1270.0485,629.5266 1270.9236,629.8396 1271.7550,630.2175 C 1273.0518,630.8075 1271.6191,633.6975 1272.6739,635.0305 C 1273.5138,636.0936 1272.9545,637.6756 1273.8571,638.5656 C 1274.3663,639.0685 1274.7839,640.2415 1275.0998,640.9055 C 1275.4444,641.6305 1276.8852,641.6706 1277.5507,641.9706 C 1278.1674,642.2495 1278.2263,642.5166 1278.5415,643.0295 C 1278.9262,643.6566 1279.7688,643.5996 1280.2970,644.0376 C 1279.5800,644.3866 1278.9324,644.3686 1278.2687,643.8926 C 1277.1797,646.3805 1280.5917,649.2666 1282.6372,650.2075 C 1284.2504,650.9506 1285.0612,649.0245 1286.2036,649.3536 C 1287.1429,649.6236 1287.4035,651.1395 1287.7688,651.8845 C 1285.3305,652.8565 1287.4159,654.2085 1288.3626,655.9435 C 1289.3741,657.7985 1286.9375,660.4876 1285.1100,660.6055 C 1284.6584,660.6345 1282.9055,661.1395 1282.5764,660.8795 C 1281.6698,660.1656 1281.4726,660.5295 1280.7295,661.1996 C 1279.2629,662.5216 1278.4465,664.3056 1276.5475,664.5276 C 1274.6376,664.7515 1273.2779,663.9085 1271.4222,663.6136 C 1270.5920,663.4815 1269.6603,663.1535 1268.8169,663.3116 C 1268.1582,663.4356 1266.0099,665.2206 1265.6251,664.9646 C 1263.5496,663.5886 1259.5502,664.3156 1257.1342,664.4886 C 1254.3736,664.6866 1251.5853,664.5846 1248.8264,664.3406 C 1249.1750,665.4295 1248.0559,666.2415 1248.0692,667.2926 C 1248.0865,668.6616 1248.9539,670.0045 1249.1690,671.3696 C 1249.3600,672.5806 1249.6622,673.9306 1249.4776,675.1535 C 1249.3078,676.2705 1250.2697,677.6345 1249.5003,678.2365 C 1248.2251,677.2966 1246.9942,675.0385 1246.1201,673.7015 C 1245.4097,674.7745 1242.4745,673.4896 1241.3511,673.9176 C 1240.1228,674.3855 1237.5435,674.7626 1237.5499,676.5095 C 1236.7687,676.3765 1234.5288,675.7225 1234.0581,675.1196 C 1233.7101,674.6735 1232.4892,673.8256 1232.5097,673.3715 C 1232.5424,672.6555 1231.5102,670.8715 1230.8821,670.5335 C 1229.8253,669.9625 1228.6690,670.7966 1228.2624,669.2376"
       id="bf1" />
  </g>
  <g
     class="land fr"
     id="fr">
    <title>France</title>
    <path
       d="M 1246.8471,351.4295 C 1246.4566,351.0935 1246.0255,350.8045 1245.5541,350.5655 C 1245.7067,351.1315 1246.1678,351.5265 1246.8471,351.4295"
       id="path2166" />
    <path
       d="M 1254.0979,354.6695 C 1253.8420,354.2105 1253.8339,354.0415 1253.1600,354.1655 C 1253.4720,354.3335 1253.7850,354.5015 1254.0979,354.6695"
       id="path2168" />
    <path
       d="M 1260.6755,361.0055 C 1260.3435,360.4335 1259.4812,360.5575 1258.9551,360.6455 C 1259.5487,360.6635 1260.1230,360.7835 1260.6755,361.0055"
       id="path2172" />
    <path
       d="M 1261.1764,363.9575 C 1261.6806,363.2525 1260.9907,362.0465 1259.9629,362.5175 C 1260.4945,362.9155 1260.8997,363.3955 1261.1764,363.9575"
       id="path2174" />
    <path
       d="M 1234.2998,345.0935 C 1235.2769,344.6715 1236.4714,344.4075 1237.6120,344.5895 C 1237.8716,343.0755 1235.6703,344.1165 1235.0981,343.0775 C 1236.1261,342.7705 1237.3659,342.8835 1238.4586,342.9325 C 1237.5926,342.8035 1236.4581,343.0705 1236.9873,342.1405 C 1236.3254,342.1095 1234.1833,343.2195 1233.8244,342.2485 C 1233.3349,340.9235 1235.5663,340.1235 1236.6473,339.9335 C 1238.1011,339.6775 1239.4839,339.5735 1240.9840,339.6095 C 1243.1079,339.6605 1244.3172,337.8595 1246.6886,338.1085 C 1246.4752,338.7735 1249.4790,341.0955 1250.2450,340.8165 C 1250.7574,340.5905 1251.2481,340.3325 1251.7161,340.0445 C 1252.7474,339.5235 1252.7271,340.1965 1253.6326,340.3465 C 1254.5274,340.4945 1255.1588,339.8845 1255.3084,341.1335 C 1255.8607,340.7865 1254.9809,340.3715 1255.4147,339.8065 C 1255.8584,339.2295 1256.1687,340.1055 1256.6018,340.2035 C 1257.6303,340.4355 1258.9087,340.1995 1259.9129,340.0535 C 1257.7191,339.5005 1258.3221,336.8345 1258.3992,335.4455 C 1258.4363,334.7695 1257.2131,334.0915 1256.7801,333.6195 C 1256.0332,332.8065 1256.5764,331.5705 1255.5392,330.9085 C 1256.3002,331.0225 1257.0094,331.3425 1257.7658,331.4775 C 1258.5931,331.6255 1259.5522,330.9285 1260.2912,331.2425 C 1261.4423,331.7305 1260.1535,333.1965 1261.7519,333.9665 C 1262.2127,334.1885 1262.9855,333.7935 1263.4445,333.7895 C 1264.7870,333.7785 1266.1047,334.1745 1267.4237,334.3905 C 1268.7120,334.6015 1269.8194,334.5695 1270.9269,334.0005 C 1271.9318,333.4855 1273.3190,333.5045 1274.2194,332.9255 C 1273.4926,333.1815 1272.2393,333.3115 1271.4947,332.9515 C 1269.9841,332.2205 1273.2547,330.4225 1273.8034,330.2035 C 1275.5478,329.5095 1277.5732,329.5925 1279.3506,328.9625 C 1280.3832,328.5975 1281.6745,326.5095 1283.0144,327.0935 C 1281.8344,326.4545 1282.3040,322.0295 1283.2164,321.2005 C 1284.1157,320.3865 1288.8411,318.9145 1290.1162,319.8095 C 1290.7651,320.2655 1289.6153,322.0198 1291.4695,322.4109 C 1293.3788,322.8139 1292.9219,322.4462 1294.2750,322.7942 C 1295.5360,323.1192 1295.1797,323.9499 1296.1615,324.3539 C 1297.4414,324.8809 1298.6887,324.2555 1298.5975,325.9395 C 1299.3300,325.5205 1300.6328,325.6175 1301.4378,325.8545 C 1302.9489,326.2985 1302.3760,327.8935 1302.1099,328.8195 C 1303.1122,328.9645 1304.2522,329.2335 1305.2327,328.8895 C 1306.2034,328.5485 1306.3961,327.5755 1307.3729,327.2355 C 1307.4755,327.7715 1307.2946,330.1685 1308.1314,330.1945 C 1309.3658,330.2325 1311.8886,331.6455 1312.3007,332.6725 C 1312.1820,332.3765 1316.9880,333.0505 1317.2343,333.0685 C 1318.4000,333.1555 1319.2636,332.9465 1320.2045,333.7835 C 1320.9441,334.4435 1321.4764,335.4805 1322.5832,335.7315 C 1322.8174,335.6335 1323.0037,335.4875 1323.1421,335.2935 C 1323.4913,334.9725 1323.6784,335.3985 1324.0565,335.4435 C 1324.2687,335.5135 1324.3272,335.6395 1324.2320,335.8205 C 1324.1740,336.2125 1325.2221,335.9985 1325.3965,336.0115 C 1326.5704,336.1045 1327.2339,335.4735 1328.3307,336.1945 C 1329.4964,336.9625 1331.8834,337.1045 1333.3296,337.3155 C 1331.5754,338.6805 1329.9629,340.1785 1329.4204,342.2065 C 1329.1574,343.1925 1328.5020,344.0985 1328.3405,345.0925 C 1328.2342,345.7425 1328.4895,346.0065 1328.2054,346.8415 C 1327.8642,347.8505 1328.7484,348.6915 1327.9877,349.3175 C 1327.3475,349.8455 1326.8548,350.3545 1325.8792,350.2775 C 1325.0611,350.2135 1324.9731,349.1465 1323.9977,349.6295 C 1323.2936,349.9785 1323.2469,351.0925 1324.4294,350.9255 C 1323.5538,351.7515 1322.7865,352.7325 1321.7852,353.4455 C 1321.1704,353.8035 1320.5698,354.1795 1319.9835,354.5735 C 1319.5024,354.9635 1319.5651,355.7275 1319.1626,356.1815 C 1318.4761,356.9555 1317.1235,357.3195 1316.9335,358.4135 C 1317.0993,358.7865 1317.2158,359.1705 1317.2852,359.5645 C 1317.1331,360.2735 1316.3977,360.5265 1316.1060,361.1485 C 1317.4379,360.9995 1317.9192,360.5935 1318.2494,359.4575 C 1318.5760,358.3395 1320.8974,358.4255 1321.8398,358.6605 C 1322.9706,358.9435 1322.2363,360.5875 1323.0689,361.3885 C 1324.5122,362.7805 1323.6479,363.3025 1322.3882,364.2455 C 1323.0794,365.1025 1325.6582,366.6905 1324.9747,367.9465 C 1324.5168,368.7895 1321.0245,369.9465 1321.0362,370.0905 C 1321.1177,371.0845 1323.2707,371.9315 1324.0175,372.4985 C 1325.0939,373.3185 1322.5698,374.7795 1322.9555,375.8635 C 1323.4221,377.1795 1326.2384,378.6715 1327.7090,378.1385 C 1329.5579,377.4695 1329.2916,378.4425 1328.6036,379.5555 C 1326.9499,382.2365 1323.7493,383.5885 1320.9086,385.3415 C 1321.0941,385.5855 1321.2861,385.8255 1321.4845,386.0615 C 1320.4166,386.2005 1319.5300,386.6985 1318.5334,387.0165 C 1317.4617,387.3595 1316.7621,386.8195 1315.7457,386.8925 C 1314.2035,387.0025 1313.2301,385.8365 1311.3854,385.9895 C 1312.0864,384.2585 1308.9482,385.5855 1308.8873,384.5795 C 1309.0806,384.2675 1309.3949,384.1855 1309.8299,384.3335 C 1309.7826,383.7665 1309.3985,383.4465 1308.7683,383.4695 C 1309.3157,384.2035 1308.8628,384.3115 1308.1337,384.3445 C 1306.9375,384.3985 1306.8064,384.3345 1306.4440,383.0375 C 1306.9458,385.6205 1306.1717,383.9735 1304.3233,383.9735 C 1303.2548,383.9735 1302.3628,383.3635 1301.3179,383.3175 C 1300.0368,383.2605 1298.6767,384.5665 1297.5566,385.0365 C 1296.6846,385.4035 1293.6064,386.4475 1293.8405,387.5365 C 1293.8322,387.8935 1293.7271,388.2255 1293.5218,388.5325 C 1293.0411,388.9325 1293.0958,389.2885 1293.6864,389.6005 C 1294.1660,390.8525 1293.9025,391.4795 1294.7461,392.6865 C 1293.9974,392.8835 1293.3266,392.5375 1292.5801,392.5785 C 1291.8051,392.6215 1291.4317,393.1835 1290.7454,393.3555 C 1289.0890,393.7705 1288.0095,392.1955 1286.4485,393.2565 C 1286.3393,393.3305 1284.0732,392.3845 1283.8266,392.2215 C 1283.1863,391.7985 1284.6136,391.8525 1283.5849,391.2435 C 1282.9889,390.8905 1281.9351,390.7355 1281.4667,391.3175 C 1281.1824,390.0285 1279.6339,390.5675 1278.7521,389.9555 C 1277.5347,389.1105 1275.0956,388.5685 1275.5659,390.5985 C 1274.2394,390.4255 1272.7368,390.1235 1271.4180,390.3455 C 1270.6850,390.4685 1270.2011,390.6585 1269.5440,390.1425 C 1268.3767,389.2285 1268.4810,389.6045 1267.3418,389.5905 C 1266.2126,389.5765 1260.5721,386.3305 1260.0884,387.6465 C 1259.0340,387.2605 1259.7274,386.5805 1259.7544,385.9255 C 1259.7866,385.1465 1257.3043,385.5015 1256.7461,384.9105 C 1259.8464,383.8515 1259.8851,379.8875 1260.3150,377.3095 C 1260.4848,376.2975 1260.5994,374.7025 1261.4946,373.9805 C 1262.7991,372.9285 1260.9610,372.7805 1260.8992,373.9665 C 1260.5711,371.5305 1260.9316,368.5455 1261.9668,366.3345 C 1263.1338,366.9035 1264.3007,367.5785 1264.8536,368.7105 C 1264.9936,369.2145 1265.1313,369.7185 1265.2690,370.2225 C 1265.5688,370.8635 1266.2893,370.9515 1266.3146,371.7345 C 1266.5828,370.7275 1265.3956,369.9525 1265.2342,368.9985 C 1264.9847,367.5325 1264.3482,366.5395 1262.8488,365.8265 C 1262.2199,365.5285 1261.5132,365.1215 1260.9768,364.6845 C 1260.1030,363.9725 1262.2884,364.3275 1262.7497,364.6795 C 1261.7043,364.2385 1261.4076,360.3855 1261.9536,359.6395 C 1260.6643,360.4745 1257.4004,358.8315 1256.7048,357.7245 C 1256.0888,356.7455 1254.8109,356.2365 1254.4845,355.0935 C 1254.1847,354.0505 1256.2678,352.9085 1253.5428,352.8005 C 1253.8378,352.4675 1253.8547,351.8625 1254.2487,351.6085 C 1255.2362,350.9705 1256.2679,352.0435 1257.2499,352.1525 C 1255.4470,351.1435 1254.7846,351.4785 1252.9961,351.6865 C 1252.0953,351.7915 1250.2424,350.6065 1251.9037,350.4245 C 1251.4046,350.0175 1251.5736,349.7535 1252.4100,349.6325 C 1251.1017,349.3505 1249.3453,350.2745 1248.2212,349.2725 C 1248.7967,349.2655 1249.3316,349.1455 1249.8260,348.9125 C 1248.7530,348.3085 1246.8821,348.5535 1246.7083,349.7765 C 1246.6065,348.9765 1245.5396,348.2285 1246.4492,347.5455 C 1246.1238,348.4215 1244.3365,348.3645 1245.3583,347.2575 C 1243.2377,348.9875 1239.8674,345.0485 1237.7538,347.1855 C 1236.7375,346.0685 1235.9092,345.3825 1234.2998,345.0935"
       id="path2182" />
    <path
       d="M 1336.1762,393.1175 C 1336.6274,392.7025 1336.7119,391.8605 1337.3165,391.5835 C 1338.5241,391.0335 1339.8919,390.8915 1341.0365,390.1985 C 1342.0590,389.5795 1341.3294,387.8345 1342.7254,387.9325 C 1342.8992,390.1285 1344.0677,393.2935 1343.4988,395.4205 C 1342.9023,397.6645 1341.6986,399.8095 1340.6445,401.8995 C 1340.2296,401.3065 1336.3600,400.0175 1338.4210,399.2355 C 1337.8629,399.1165 1337.3359,398.9245 1336.8402,398.6605 C 1337.3826,398.3485 1337.7619,397.8275 1337.6968,397.2205 C 1336.5963,397.4575 1336.4295,396.3335 1337.0623,395.7815 C 1336.1190,395.5655 1335.5177,394.4395 1336.8101,394.1975 C 1336.5398,393.8655 1336.3284,393.5065 1336.1762,393.1175"
       id="path2184" />
  </g>
```

This is the code I have tried so far

```
var countries = document.getElementsByTagName('g');
for (var i = 0; i < countries.length; i++) {
  var country = countries[i];
  var title = country.childNodes[1];
  var path = country.childNodes[2];
}
```

I am not sure how to get to the title.text or the actual path data. Do I use xml methods to get this or trying to put this into arrays?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get title you can achieve that by using [textContent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent):

```
var title = country.getElementsByTagName('title')[0].textContent;
```

to get paths data:

```
var paths = country.getElementsByTagName('path');
```

then loop through paths since a country in this SVG might have multiple `<path>` tag, then get the attribute `d` from the path using [element.getAttribute()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute)

```
paths[i].getAttribute('d')
```

Here is a working snippet:

```js
var countries = document.getElementsByTagName('g');
for (var i = 0; i < countries.length; i++) {
    var country = countries[i];
    var title = country.getElementsByTagName('title')[0].textContent;
    console.log('Title', title);
    var paths = country.getElementsByTagName('path');
    console.log(paths[0].getAttribute('d'));
    
    //for (var j = 0; j < paths.length; j++) {
      // YOU CAN LOOP HERE
      //console.log(paths[i].getAttribute('d'));
    //}

}
```

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<svg
   xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
   viewBox="-29.947200 60.986600 2754.066400 1200.573900"
   version="1.1"
   id="WorldMap">
  <g class="land pe" id="pe">
    <title>Peru</title>
    <path
       d="M 648.6568,798.4085 C 649.7424,796.3496 650.3516,794.9406 651.9945,793.1866 C 652.7283,792.4035 653.3084,791.4646 654.1824,790.8206 C 654.8156,790.3536 656.1752,789.7275 656.2689,788.8275 C 657.2520,789.1115 658.1313,793.1756 657.2450,793.6835 C 656.5998,794.0535 655.8948,793.7206 655.4142,794.3655 C 654.8657,795.1005 654.9399,796.1025 655.9582,796.2476 C 655.0648,797.3736 655.3714,799.0856 656.7668,797.6486 C 657.9912,796.3876 658.4138,796.9855 659.4871,797.9275 C 660.4068,798.7355 661.5495,797.5105 662.2500,798.7265 C 662.9692,799.9765 662.9082,802.0466 664.6843,802.3836 C 666.1842,802.6685 666.3388,802.8536 666.9148,801.2065 C 667.3747,799.8926 668.8395,799.5646 668.9609,798.2225 C 669.1248,796.4066 669.4767,794.7626 670.2927,793.0775 C 670.7117,792.2115 671.2559,791.5865 671.3107,790.5906 C 671.3456,789.9585 672.1519,788.2096 672.4408,789.9076 C 672.6979,789.5176 672.7618,789.1075 672.6322,788.6785 C 672.5967,788.1255 673.4299,787.5276 673.7411,787.1366 C 674.5513,786.1155 675.5439,785.3586 676.7253,784.8275 C 679.2958,783.6716 682.2668,783.2465 684.6343,781.6486 C 689.6128,778.2866 693.1525,773.2536 694.1922,767.5176 C 694.5872,767.9345 695.0666,768.1005 695.6324,768.0176 C 694.9156,766.3575 695.6582,764.8886 694.6639,763.4715 C 694.2726,762.9135 692.3296,761.2165 692.4480,760.5276 C 693.2653,760.6666 694.2190,760.9456 694.9920,760.4865 C 695.7580,760.0326 695.5146,759.8845 696.3804,760.2056 C 697.8738,760.7586 698.9792,761.3505 700.0121,762.5915 C 701.3548,764.2065 702.1132,764.8025 702.7589,766.8676 C 703.0289,767.7286 702.6975,768.4325 703.8848,768.5355 C 705.0360,768.6355 704.7361,769.0956 705.5337,769.8066 C 707.0808,771.1875 708.2162,770.4525 708.7595,772.8095 C 709.1376,774.6355 709.0426,775.0746 710.9673,775.6576 C 713.0414,776.2855 710.9656,778.7336 711.9900,779.9535 C 712.5458,780.6146 713.4435,780.8396 714.2932,780.8045 C 714.8252,780.7336 715.3592,780.6866 715.8943,780.6626 C 716.6026,780.6645 717.4140,781.0806 718.0432,781.0585 C 719.4889,781.0045 721.2381,779.9646 721.9121,778.7056 C 722.6237,777.3765 724.3541,779.9176 725.1421,779.9786 C 726.3301,780.0706 728.2345,778.3475 729.0595,778.9686 C 729.7181,779.4646 730.2872,780.2165 730.9228,780.6635 C 731.5330,781.0936 733.0100,780.9765 733.3800,781.3855 C 734.8927,783.0556 734.8944,783.6576 733.5911,785.6055 C 732.5473,787.1656 730.5320,789.8346 730.1908,791.6495 C 729.7822,793.8206 732.3497,792.1205 733.2592,792.9406 C 733.9935,793.6015 734.5523,794.4886 735.0578,795.3306 C 735.6388,796.2956 735.1639,797.8425 734.3336,796.3886 C 734.1314,796.6286 733.9292,796.8686 733.7260,797.1086 C 732.6592,795.5846 730.2059,794.5925 728.7222,796.3795 C 727.0303,798.4176 723.5334,797.8795 721.1886,798.4936 C 719.9605,798.8156 719.3212,800.1635 718.1019,800.5385 C 716.8207,800.9335 717.2130,801.4406 716.3405,802.1985 C 714.2491,804.0176 712.8686,803.4955 712.7185,806.6136 C 712.6658,807.6946 712.6970,808.6005 712.0264,809.5416 C 711.3875,810.4366 710.6312,811.3335 710.8275,812.4805 C 711.0311,813.6706 711.9944,815.3626 710.6256,816.2805 C 709.4738,817.0516 708.3977,817.4456 707.4366,818.5205 C 706.7353,819.3045 706.3517,820.1956 706.5261,821.2286 C 706.6220,821.7286 706.7778,822.2096 706.9893,822.6685 C 706.4175,822.9116 705.8207,823.2165 705.3775,823.6695 C 703.6677,825.4176 708.4053,826.9345 706.3765,828.1376 C 707.3528,828.7926 707.9942,829.9886 708.1536,831.1526 C 708.2468,831.8335 708.7066,832.0706 709.1822,832.4675 C 709.7778,832.9636 709.6850,833.7196 710.0652,834.3375 C 710.7335,835.4206 712.0936,835.9306 712.5405,837.1845 C 713.0738,838.6795 711.8784,839.5925 711.0049,840.6676 C 712.7472,841.5975 715.4084,840.7616 717.1280,841.9345 C 718.2446,842.6956 719.2182,844.6735 718.7153,846.0675 C 721.1000,846.3676 724.1416,846.8845 726.3491,845.4316 C 727.7360,844.5145 729.6379,841.1996 731.4507,841.1775 C 731.2004,842.0445 730.5215,842.0886 731.0143,842.9846 C 731.5367,843.9356 730.5505,844.8845 730.5627,845.9706 C 730.5164,848.7945 730.3850,851.6906 730.5071,854.4976 C 731.5035,853.6845 732.0031,855.3465 732.9821,855.2526 C 734.3321,855.1226 735.3554,854.0525 736.7296,854.0856 C 737.9924,854.1155 738.7376,854.0506 739.2868,855.2376 C 740.1215,857.0385 740.9835,858.8166 741.8451,860.6055 C 742.7133,862.4066 743.5578,864.2215 744.4773,865.9955 C 745.1519,867.2945 745.7043,868.6255 744.1880,869.8396 C 742.8701,870.8945 743.0925,872.2736 743.1166,873.7405 C 743.1421,875.3346 742.4278,877.7125 742.8745,879.1566 C 743.1456,880.0316 743.9232,880.8565 743.8892,881.8285 C 743.8866,881.8886 742.8649,884.1946 742.7925,884.2555 C 741.8466,885.0476 741.0765,886.3406 740.5795,887.4456 C 739.6706,889.4646 741.8021,889.7785 741.6853,891.3475 C 741.6017,892.4615 740.5011,893.3845 740.2068,894.4646 C 739.9236,895.4145 740.4587,896.5975 740.7109,897.4575 C 740.9458,898.2576 741.3073,899.7835 742.3012,899.9656 C 742.7808,900.0535 745.3417,900.2505 743.6572,901.2465 C 742.5273,901.9145 743.2999,903.5276 742.5924,903.8926 C 741.2536,904.5846 740.8089,906.4485 739.7335,907.3955 C 739.2650,907.8085 738.6654,908.0326 738.2661,908.5295 C 737.5099,909.4706 738.5389,909.1735 738.9383,909.7945 C 739.9792,911.4166 737.4347,911.7826 736.8339,912.7876 C 736.1577,913.9166 737.2394,915.2595 736.3213,916.5556 C 735.5304,917.6716 734.0881,918.0666 732.8543,918.0666 C 731.4693,918.0666 730.5228,917.0476 729.6863,916.1756 C 728.6999,915.1486 727.5449,914.6676 726.4464,913.8315 C 724.4979,912.3486 724.9775,909.6505 722.5556,908.6205 C 719.6903,907.4005 718.0102,904.4986 714.9184,903.7246 C 713.4715,903.3626 712.0639,902.3456 710.8658,901.5495 C 709.4321,900.5975 707.7951,900.2785 706.3194,899.4375 C 704.8757,898.6126 703.7196,897.3525 702.2787,896.4805 C 700.6585,895.5005 699.0337,894.5395 697.3552,893.5865 C 695.9376,892.7816 695.1975,890.9356 694.1291,889.7465 C 692.7138,888.1706 690.6028,887.3425 689.6862,885.3866 C 689.1697,884.2826 688.5055,882.9565 687.4919,882.2916 C 686.6056,881.7096 688.0364,879.4855 686.3740,879.7655 C 686.4171,879.4846 686.5114,879.2175 686.6599,878.9656 C 686.8918,879.1096 687.1215,879.2565 687.3490,879.4055 C 688.2656,876.2075 687.0116,874.5495 685.6182,871.9295 C 684.3528,869.5495 683.5698,867.0326 681.6786,865.0975 C 681.1118,864.5166 680.5085,864.2106 680.7444,863.4156 C 681.0157,862.5005 680.5637,861.4736 680.1889,860.7115 C 679.8211,859.9625 679.3674,859.1595 678.7466,858.5946 C 678.1754,858.0735 677.1451,857.8265 676.8187,857.0685 C 676.8045,856.6716 676.8746,856.2776 677.0277,855.8886 C 676.9801,855.0255 676.5148,854.0376 676.1852,853.2736 C 675.5541,851.8085 674.6325,850.5105 673.9153,849.0946 C 673.2396,847.7605 672.9167,846.1626 672.4266,844.7255 C 671.2835,841.3696 669.3041,838.7855 668.5163,835.5406 C 667.4405,831.1115 663.7984,828.4156 662.3009,824.0406 C 660.5645,819.0366 656.6648,815.4706 651.8435,813.4066 C 651.4191,813.2246 649.8166,812.8365 649.7868,812.2396 C 649.7458,811.4076 649.6292,810.0195 650.8206,810.1676 C 652.9402,810.4316 652.2162,808.4216 651.5710,807.3745 C 650.6605,805.8976 649.7187,805.2805 649.7454,803.4435 C 649.9528,803.2075 650.1553,802.9675 650.3529,802.7236 C 650.3287,802.4435 649.5110,801.6695 649.3308,801.4556 C 648.3827,800.3356 649.0196,799.6756 648.6568,798.4085"
       id="pe1" />

  </g>
  <g class="land gf" id="gf">
    <title>French Guiana</title>
    <path
     d="M 853.0452,739.4375 C 854.3325,739.3776 855.3084,737.1695 855.7246,736.2006 C 856.5002,734.3916 855.6456,732.3786 856.8415,730.7305 C 858.2597,728.7776 856.8800,727.3375 855.5955,725.7826 C 854.2633,724.1695 854.2465,721.2895 854.0752,719.3216 C 853.8760,717.0285 854.1794,715.7255 855.8172,714.1286 C 856.4271,713.5335 857.1889,712.8765 857.3684,711.9976 C 857.6008,710.8586 857.8616,709.4356 859.4943,710.0456 C 860.5538,710.4416 861.2942,711.2895 862.4175,711.5946 C 863.6306,711.9256 865.0940,711.9066 866.1329,712.7206 C 867.3514,713.6775 869.0259,717.3225 870.9009,717.1896 C 870.5961,717.6516 870.3914,718.1555 870.2859,718.7025 C 870.7633,716.3066 874.9695,720.4176 872.6658,722.0145 C 873.7899,721.5975 873.1066,720.5395 873.6541,719.7855 C 874.4851,718.6395 875.2123,721.3106 875.2915,721.8795 C 875.6657,724.5775 873.6586,727.4335 872.3034,729.5815 C 870.7467,732.0495 869.6730,734.1386 868.6857,736.9195 C 868.3194,737.9515 867.8364,738.8246 866.9852,739.5266 C 866.6318,739.8185 866.0021,740.4905 865.5308,740.6155 C 864.7542,740.8225 864.1243,740.1975 863.2981,740.5915 C 863.6193,739.6105 863.0038,739.6065 862.2718,739.8346 C 861.2487,740.1535 860.3584,739.7346 859.3710,739.4035 C 858.8727,739.2365 856.9837,740.6286 856.6852,740.9936 C 856.1311,741.6706 853.4319,739.8346 853.0452,739.4375"
     id="gf1" />

  </g>
  <g class="land bf" id="bf">
    <title>Burkina Faso</title>
    <path
       d="M 1228.2624,669.2376 C 1228.7782,667.8546 1229.1945,666.3886 1228.8503,664.9095 C 1228.4738,663.2926 1229.3082,664.1906 1229.9106,662.9786 C 1230.2827,662.2286 1231.3192,660.0036 1230.3779,659.3745 C 1229.6073,658.8596 1230.6017,657.5716 1229.1678,657.2146 C 1230.0071,657.2565 1230.4091,656.6055 1231.0407,656.2175 C 1232.0725,655.5856 1233.4797,656.1046 1234.5447,655.4525 C 1235.8474,654.6555 1237.7150,651.6065 1236.4155,650.2006 C 1235.8925,649.6355 1236.8673,649.0835 1237.3779,649.2025 C 1238.4587,649.4535 1238.3766,648.3425 1238.2013,647.4825 C 1238.0856,646.9206 1236.9528,646.0856 1237.9230,645.7486 C 1238.6695,645.4886 1239.6730,643.3855 1240.1331,642.7415 C 1240.0900,644.0076 1243.1214,645.5195 1244.1653,645.6226 C 1243.9033,644.4216 1244.6920,644.5806 1245.6746,644.6146 C 1245.5282,643.5166 1246.0615,642.0236 1245.4764,641.0136 C 1246.2965,641.1685 1247.1457,641.2255 1247.8856,641.6616 C 1248.9666,640.0236 1248.7870,636.4275 1251.6452,636.1345 C 1253.0537,635.9905 1254.9408,638.1605 1255.1892,635.6845 C 1255.3219,634.3565 1256.6916,634.5725 1257.6039,634.1005 C 1258.7865,633.4896 1259.6188,632.4285 1260.9221,632.0145 C 1262.8073,631.4145 1265.0735,627.6845 1267.1804,629.5416 C 1267.5803,629.8936 1268.5339,629.0746 1269.1731,629.2655 C 1270.0485,629.5266 1270.9236,629.8396 1271.7550,630.2175 C 1273.0518,630.8075 1271.6191,633.6975 1272.6739,635.0305 C 1273.5138,636.0936 1272.9545,637.6756 1273.8571,638.5656 C 1274.3663,639.0685 1274.7839,640.2415 1275.0998,640.9055 C 1275.4444,641.6305 1276.8852,641.6706 1277.5507,641.9706 C 1278.1674,642.2495 1278.2263,642.5166 1278.5415,643.0295 C 1278.9262,643.6566 1279.7688,643.5996 1280.2970,644.0376 C 1279.5800,644.3866 1278.9324,644.3686 1278.2687,643.8926 C 1277.1797,646.3805 1280.5917,649.2666 1282.6372,650.2075 C 1284.2504,650.9506 1285.0612,649.0245 1286.2036,649.3536 C 1287.1429,649.6236 1287.4035,651.1395 1287.7688,651.8845 C 1285.3305,652.8565 1287.4159,654.2085 1288.3626,655.9435 C 1289.3741,657.7985 1286.9375,660.4876 1285.1100,660.6055 C 1284.6584,660.6345 1282.9055,661.1395 1282.5764,660.8795 C 1281.6698,660.1656 1281.4726,660.5295 1280.7295,661.1996 C 1279.2629,662.5216 1278.4465,664.3056 1276.5475,664.5276 C 1274.6376,664.7515 1273.2779,663.9085 1271.4222,663.6136 C 1270.5920,663.4815 1269.6603,663.1535 1268.8169,663.3116 C 1268.1582,663.4356 1266.0099,665.2206 1265.6251,664.9646 C 1263.5496,663.5886 1259.5502,664.3156 1257.1342,664.4886 C 1254.3736,664.6866 1251.5853,664.5846 1248.8264,664.3406 C 1249.1750,665.4295 1248.0559,666.2415 1248.0692,667.2926 C 1248.0865,668.6616 1248.9539,670.0045 1249.1690,671.3696 C 1249.3600,672.5806 1249.6622,673.9306 1249.4776,675.1535 C 1249.3078,676.2705 1250.2697,677.6345 1249.5003,678.2365 C 1248.2251,677.2966 1246.9942,675.0385 1246.1201,673.7015 C 1245.4097,674.7745 1242.4745,673.4896 1241.3511,673.9176 C 1240.1228,674.3855 1237.5435,674.7626 1237.5499,676.5095 C 1236.7687,676.3765 1234.5288,675.7225 1234.0581,675.1196 C 1233.7101,674.6735 1232.4892,673.8256 1232.5097,673.3715 C 1232.5424,672.6555 1231.5102,670.8715 1230.8821,670.5335 C 1229.8253,669.9625 1228.6690,670.7966 1228.2624,669.2376"
       id="bf1" />
  </g>
  <g
     class="land fr"
     id="fr">
    <title>France</title>
    <path
       d="M 1246.8471,351.4295 C 1246.4566,351.0935 1246.0255,350.8045 1245.5541,350.5655 C 1245.7067,351.1315 1246.1678,351.5265 1246.8471,351.4295"
       id="path2166" />
    <path
       d="M 1254.0979,354.6695 C 1253.8420,354.2105 1253.8339,354.0415 1253.1600,354.1655 C 1253.4720,354.3335 1253.7850,354.5015 1254.0979,354.6695"
       id="path2168" />
    <path
       d="M 1260.6755,361.0055 C 1260.3435,360.4335 1259.4812,360.5575 1258.9551,360.6455 C 1259.5487,360.6635 1260.1230,360.7835 1260.6755,361.0055"
       id="path2172" />
    <path
       d="M 1261.1764,363.9575 C 1261.6806,363.2525 1260.9907,362.0465 1259.9629,362.5175 C 1260.4945,362.9155 1260.8997,363.3955 1261.1764,363.9575"
       id="path2174" />
    <path
       d="M 1234.2998,345.0935 C 1235.2769,344.6715 1236.4714,344.4075 1237.6120,344.5895 C 1237.8716,343.0755 1235.6703,344.1165 1235.0981,343.0775 C 1236.1261,342.7705 1237.3659,342.8835 1238.4586,342.9325 C 1237.5926,342.8035 1236.4581,343.0705 1236.9873,342.1405 C 1236.3254,342.1095 1234.1833,343.2195 1233.8244,342.2485 C 1233.3349,340.9235 1235.5663,340.1235 1236.6473,339.9335 C 1238.1011,339.6775 1239.4839,339.5735 1240.9840,339.6095 C 1243.1079,339.6605 1244.3172,337.8595 1246.6886,338.1085 C 1246.4752,338.7735 1249.4790,341.0955 1250.2450,340.8165 C 1250.7574,340.5905 1251.2481,340.3325 1251.7161,340.0445 C 1252.7474,339.5235 1252.7271,340.1965 1253.6326,340.3465 C 1254.5274,340.4945 1255.1588,339.8845 1255.3084,341.1335 C 1255.8607,340.7865 1254.9809,340.3715 1255.4147,339.8065 C 1255.8584,339.2295 1256.1687,340.1055 1256.6018,340.2035 C 1257.6303,340.4355 1258.9087,340.1995 1259.9129,340.0535 C 1257.7191,339.5005 1258.3221,336.8345 1258.3992,335.4455 C 1258.4363,334.7695 1257.2131,334.0915 1256.7801,333.6195 C 1256.0332,332.8065 1256.5764,331.5705 1255.5392,330.9085 C 1256.3002,331.0225 1257.0094,331.3425 1257.7658,331.4775 C 1258.5931,331.6255 1259.5522,330.9285 1260.2912,331.2425 C 1261.4423,331.7305 1260.1535,333.1965 1261.7519,333.9665 C 1262.2127,334.1885 1262.9855,333.7935 1263.4445,333.7895 C 1264.7870,333.7785 1266.1047,334.1745 1267.4237,334.3905 C 1268.7120,334.6015 1269.8194,334.5695 1270.9269,334.0005 C 1271.9318,333.4855 1273.3190,333.5045 1274.2194,332.9255 C 1273.4926,333.1815 1272.2393,333.3115 1271.4947,332.9515 C 1269.9841,332.2205 1273.2547,330.4225 1273.8034,330.2035 C 1275.5478,329.5095 1277.5732,329.5925 1279.3506,328.9625 C 1280.3832,328.5975 1281.6745,326.5095 1283.0144,327.0935 C 1281.8344,326.4545 1282.3040,322.0295 1283.2164,321.2005 C 1284.1157,320.3865 1288.8411,318.9145 1290.1162,319.8095 C 1290.7651,320.2655 1289.6153,322.0198 1291.4695,322.4109 C 1293.3788,322.8139 1292.9219,322.4462 1294.2750,322.7942 C 1295.5360,323.1192 1295.1797,323.9499 1296.1615,324.3539 C 1297.4414,324.8809 1298.6887,324.2555 1298.5975,325.9395 C 1299.3300,325.5205 1300.6328,325.6175 1301.4378,325.8545 C 1302.9489,326.2985 1302.3760,327.8935 1302.1099,328.8195 C 1303.1122,328.9645 1304.2522,329.2335 1305.2327,328.8895 C 1306.2034,328.5485 1306.3961,327.5755 1307.3729,327.2355 C 1307.4755,327.7715 1307.2946,330.1685 1308.1314,330.1945 C 1309.3658,330.2325 1311.8886,331.6455 1312.3007,332.6725 C 1312.1820,332.3765 1316.9880,333.0505 1317.2343,333.0685 C 1318.4000,333.1555 1319.2636,332.9465 1320.2045,333.7835 C 1320.9441,334.4435 1321.4764,335.4805 1322.5832,335.7315 C 1322.8174,335.6335 1323.0037,335.4875 1323.1421,335.2935 C 1323.4913,334.9725 1323.6784,335.3985 1324.0565,335.4435 C 1324.2687,335.5135 1324.3272,335.6395 1324.2320,335.8205 C 1324.1740,336.2125 1325.2221,335.9985 1325.3965,336.0115 C 1326.5704,336.1045 1327.2339,335.4735 1328.3307,336.1945 C 1329.4964,336.9625 1331.8834,337.1045 1333.3296,337.3155 C 1331.5754,338.6805 1329.9629,340.1785 1329.4204,342.2065 C 1329.1574,343.1925 1328.5020,344.0985 1328.3405,345.0925 C 1328.2342,345.7425 1328.4895,346.0065 1328.2054,346.8415 C 1327.8642,347.8505 1328.7484,348.6915 1327.9877,349.3175 C 1327.3475,349.8455 1326.8548,350.3545 1325.8792,350.2775 C 1325.0611,350.2135 1324.9731,349.1465 1323.9977,349.6295 C 1323.2936,349.9785 1323.2469,351.0925 1324.4294,350.9255 C 1323.5538,351.7515 1322.7865,352.7325 1321.7852,353.4455 C 1321.1704,353.8035 1320.5698,354.1795 1319.9835,354.5735 C 1319.5024,354.9635 1319.5651,355.7275 1319.1626,356.1815 C 1318.4761,356.9555 1317.1235,357.3195 1316.9335,358.4135 C 1317.0993,358.7865 1317.2158,359.1705 1317.2852,359.5645 C 1317.1331,360.2735 1316.3977,360.5265 1316.1060,361.1485 C 1317.4379,360.9995 1317.9192,360.5935 1318.2494,359.4575 C 1318.5760,358.3395 1320.8974,358.4255 1321.8398,358.6605 C 1322.9706,358.9435 1322.2363,360.5875 1323.0689,361.3885 C 1324.5122,362.7805 1323.6479,363.3025 1322.3882,364.2455 C 1323.0794,365.1025 1325.6582,366.6905 1324.9747,367.9465 C 1324.5168,368.7895 1321.0245,369.9465 1321.0362,370.0905 C 1321.1177,371.0845 1323.2707,371.9315 1324.0175,372.4985 C 1325.0939,373.3185 1322.5698,374.7795 1322.9555,375.8635 C 1323.4221,377.1795 1326.2384,378.6715 1327.7090,378.1385 C 1329.5579,377.4695 1329.2916,378.4425 1328.6036,379.5555 C 1326.9499,382.2365 1323.7493,383.5885 1320.9086,385.3415 C 1321.0941,385.5855 1321.2861,385.8255 1321.4845,386.0615 C 1320.4166,386.2005 1319.5300,386.6985 1318.5334,387.0165 C 1317.4617,387.3595 1316.7621,386.8195 1315.7457,386.8925 C 1314.2035,387.0025 1313.2301,385.8365 1311.3854,385.9895 C 1312.0864,384.2585 1308.9482,385.5855 1308.8873,384.5795 C 1309.0806,384.2675 1309.3949,384.1855 1309.8299,384.3335 C 1309.7826,383.7665 1309.3985,383.4465 1308.7683,383.4695 C 1309.3157,384.2035 1308.8628,384.3115 1308.1337,384.3445 C 1306.9375,384.3985 1306.8064,384.3345 1306.4440,383.0375 C 1306.9458,385.6205 1306.1717,383.9735 1304.3233,383.9735 C 1303.2548,383.9735 1302.3628,383.3635 1301.3179,383.3175 C 1300.0368,383.2605 1298.6767,384.5665 1297.5566,385.0365 C 1296.6846,385.4035 1293.6064,386.4475 1293.8405,387.5365 C 1293.8322,387.8935 1293.7271,388.2255 1293.5218,388.5325 C 1293.0411,388.9325 1293.0958,389.2885 1293.6864,389.6005 C 1294.1660,390.8525 1293.9025,391.4795 1294.7461,392.6865 C 1293.9974,392.8835 1293.3266,392.5375 1292.5801,392.5785 C 1291.8051,392.6215 1291.4317,393.1835 1290.7454,393.3555 C 1289.0890,393.7705 1288.0095,392.1955 1286.4485,393.2565 C 1286.3393,393.3305 1284.0732,392.3845 1283.8266,392.2215 C 1283.1863,391.7985 1284.6136,391.8525 1283.5849,391.2435 C 1282.9889,390.8905 1281.9351,390.7355 1281.4667,391.3175 C 1281.1824,390.0285 1279.6339,390.5675 1278.7521,389.9555 C 1277.5347,389.1105 1275.0956,388.5685 1275.5659,390.5985 C 1274.2394,390.4255 1272.7368,390.1235 1271.4180,390.3455 C 1270.6850,390.4685 1270.2011,390.6585 1269.5440,390.1425 C 1268.3767,389.2285 1268.4810,389.6045 1267.3418,389.5905 C 1266.2126,389.5765 1260.5721,386.3305 1260.0884,387.6465 C 1259.0340,387.2605 1259.7274,386.5805 1259.7544,385.9255 C 1259.7866,385.1465 1257.3043,385.5015 1256.7461,384.9105 C 1259.8464,383.8515 1259.8851,379.8875 1260.3150,377.3095 C 1260.4848,376.2975 1260.5994,374.7025 1261.4946,373.9805 C 1262.7991,372.9285 1260.9610,372.7805 1260.8992,373.9665 C 1260.5711,371.5305 1260.9316,368.5455 1261.9668,366.3345 C 1263.1338,366.9035 1264.3007,367.5785 1264.8536,368.7105 C 1264.9936,369.2145 1265.1313,369.7185 1265.2690,370.2225 C 1265.5688,370.8635 1266.2893,370.9515 1266.3146,371.7345 C 1266.5828,370.7275 1265.3956,369.9525 1265.2342,368.9985 C 1264.9847,367.5325 1264.3482,366.5395 1262.8488,365.8265 C 1262.2199,365.5285 1261.5132,365.1215 1260.9768,364.6845 C 1260.1030,363.9725 1262.2884,364.3275 1262.7497,364.6795 C 1261.7043,364.2385 1261.4076,360.3855 1261.9536,359.6395 C 1260.6643,360.4745 1257.4004,358.8315 1256.7048,357.7245 C 1256.0888,356.7455 1254.8109,356.2365 1254.4845,355.0935 C 1254.1847,354.0505 1256.2678,352.9085 1253.5428,352.8005 C 1253.8378,352.4675 1253.8547,351.8625 1254.2487,351.6085 C 1255.2362,350.9705 1256.2679,352.0435 1257.2499,352.1525 C 1255.4470,351.1435 1254.7846,351.4785 1252.9961,351.6865 C 1252.0953,351.7915 1250.2424,350.6065 1251.9037,350.4245 C 1251.4046,350.0175 1251.5736,349.7535 1252.4100,349.6325 C 1251.1017,349.3505 1249.3453,350.2745 1248.2212,349.2725 C 1248.7967,349.2655 1249.3316,349.1455 1249.8260,348.9125 C 1248.7530,348.3085 1246.8821,348.5535 1246.7083,349.7765 C 1246.6065,348.9765 1245.5396,348.2285 1246.4492,347.5455 C 1246.1238,348.4215 1244.3365,348.3645 1245.3583,347.2575 C 1243.2377,348.9875 1239.8674,345.0485 1237.7538,347.1855 C 1236.7375,346.0685 1235.9092,345.3825 1234.2998,345.0935"
       id="path2182" />
    <path
       d="M 1336.1762,393.1175 C 1336.6274,392.7025 1336.7119,391.8605 1337.3165,391.5835 C 1338.5241,391.0335 1339.8919,390.8915 1341.0365,390.1985 C 1342.0590,389.5795 1341.3294,387.8345 1342.7254,387.9325 C 1342.8992,390.1285 1344.0677,393.2935 1343.4988,395.4205 C 1342.9023,397.6645 1341.6986,399.8095 1340.6445,401.8995 C 1340.2296,401.3065 1336.3600,400.0175 1338.4210,399.2355 C 1337.8629,399.1165 1337.3359,398.9245 1336.8402,398.6605 C 1337.3826,398.3485 1337.7619,397.8275 1337.6968,397.2205 C 1336.5963,397.4575 1336.4295,396.3335 1337.0623,395.7815 C 1336.1190,395.5655 1335.5177,394.4395 1336.8101,394.1975 C 1336.5398,393.8655 1336.3284,393.5065 1336.1762,393.1175"
       id="path2184" />
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation.